# Active azure account for learning azure

Tags: azure

I want to start learning **azure**.

I was looking at some videos and getting started tutorials.All these are showing requirement of Microsoft azure account.

Do i need active Microsoft account on cloud or can i create virtual environment on my local machine using some tool.

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you planning to use for your learning, and what parts of the infrastructure are you planning on trying out?

Comment: I am using asp.net with c# with wcf and windows services

Answer (score 1):

You can also get a trial subscription ( http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/ ) if you want to also run the Azure workloads in the cloud instead of local emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the virtual environment without Azure account.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403990.aspx), the Azure SDK includes the Windows Azure compute emulator. The compute emulator is a local emulator of Azure, so that you can build and test your application before you deploy it. Some differences exist between how applications run locally compared to how applications run in Azure. For more information, see Differences Between the Compute Emulator and Azure.

To use the compute emulator, you must download and install the [Azure SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).